# Using the Mediawiki API to return a Wikipedia page URL

Tags: wikipedia-api, wikimedia

I found out that I can use:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Stack%20Overflow
```

To retrieve the intro section of a Wikipedia page. But now I would like to get the URL of the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prop=info&inprop=url`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=extracts%7Cinfo&titles=Stack+Overflow&exintro=1&explaintext=1&inprop=url

In general, [ApiSandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) is a good way to discover the capabilities of the API.